# Hive query getting failed while trying to use TEZ engine

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-tez

I am trying to execute the below query using the TEZ engine which got executed successfully in MR engine.

```
 set hive.execution.engine=tez;SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true; SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;SET mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec; insert overwrite table df.test_table PARTITION (load_date1) SELECT * df.SRC_test_table lower(STATUS)<>lower('STATUS');
```

Below is the log for the same.

[image]

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace as text, not an image

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but isn't your FROM statement missing? And Where clause...

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a comment. Consider using the comments feature underneath the question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you might be hitting TEZ-2741.

can you try to run the query by setting below config

```
hive.compute.splits.in.am=false
```

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of hits and trails, I had found that ';' is a must thing for this new version.